# How to strip and convert string to float (decimals)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, dataframe, floating-point

I am trying to convert a string which is like "  8,191.55 MB  " to " 8191.55"
so that I can divide it by 1024 to get it in GigaBytes.

Code I am trying gives me " 819155" instead of "8191.55"

Code :

```
TotalRAM = dfHandler['Total Physical Memory'].values[0]
TotalRAM = (int)(''.join(i for i in TotalRAM if i.isdigit()))
```

Comment: Your join statement is getting rid of the decimal place. You might want to consider replacing all non-numerical characters with ‘’ and then doing a float conversion. Also, you want to use float, not int. Int will round to the nearest integer and get rid of your decimal places.

Comment: You can get around it in this case, but in general you might want to look into regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code you have, I would go for

```
TotalRAM = dfHandler['Total Physical Memory'].values[0]
TotalRAM = float(''.join(i for i in TotalRAM if (i.isdigit() or i == ".")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `replace()` to get rid of the comma values, and use `split()` to break it into parts. The split function will also get rid of the leading and trailing white space.

```
RAM = ' 8,191.55 MB '
ram_in_MB = float(RAM.replace(',','').split()[0])
print(ram_in_MB)
# 8191.55
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TotalRAM = dfHandler['Total Physical Memory'].values[0]    
TotalRAM = float(TotalRAM.replace(',', '').replace(' MB', ''))
TotalRAMGb = TotalRam / 1024
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use regular expressions (re) to extract the number part of your string. It will get numbers (d+) and decimals (.).

```
import re
num = re.findall("(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)", "8,191.55 MB")
print(float(''.join(num)))
```

result:

```
8191.55
```

Comment: Your regex is wrong - did not account for commas or numbers without decimals

Comment: you don't need the commas because float do not accept commas. I edited my answer to handle integer values. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about a more localized approach:

```py
from locale import setlocale, LC_NUMERIC, atof
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, '')

# ...

TotalRAM = dfHandler['Total Physical Memory'].values[0]
TotalRAM = atof(TotalRAM.split()[0])
```